# SAMPA and IPA pronunciation of Esperanto letters

Tags: pronunciation

To aid pronunciation, is there a table converting the letters in Esperanto to SAMPA and to IPA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From 
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononco_de_Esperanto#Literoj_kaj_fonemoj
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-SAMPA but slightly simplified to leave out the diacritical marks on the vowels.

```
Esperanto          IFA/IPA          SAMPA
a                  a                a  
b                  b                b
c                  t͡s               ts
ĉ                  t͡ʃ               tS
d                  d                d
e                  e                e
f                  f                f
g                  g                g
ĝ                  d͡ʒ               dZ
h                  h                h
ĥ                  x                x
i                  i                i
j                  j                j
ĵ                  ʒ                Z
k                  k                k
l                  l                l
m                  m                m
n                  n                n
o                  o                o
p                  p                p
r                  r                r 
s                  s                s
ŝ                  ʃ                S
t                  t                t
u                  u                u 
ŭ                  w                w
v                  v                v
z                  z                z
```

Comment: I don't think 'ä' is part of the IPA, though it states that on the Wikipedia page. In my view it should just be a simple 'a' in both IPA and SAMPA. Though I guess it depends how precise the transcription should be (phonological or phonetic). I would suggest that we simplify a, e, and o by removing the diacritics, which I believe don't add anything of value. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/The_International_Phonetic_Alphabet_%28revised_to_2015%29.pdf for details.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link includes the diacritical marks. I can remove the diacritics but it would to have a reference.

Comment: " While the International Phonetic Alphabet officially has no dedicated letter for this sound between front [a] and back [ɑ], it is normally written ⟨a⟩. If precision is required, it can be specified by using diacritics, such as centralized ⟨ä⟩ or retracted ⟨a̠⟩, but this is not common." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel)

Comment: "The mid back rounded vowel is a type of vowel sound, used in some spoken languages. While there is no dedicated symbol in the International Phonetic Alphabet that represents the exact mid back rounded vowel between close-mid [o] and open-mid [ɔ], it is normally written ⟨o⟩. If precision is desired, diacritics may be used, such as ⟨o̞⟩ or ⟨ɔ̝⟩, the former being more common. A non-IPA letter ⟨ⱺ⟩ is also found." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_back_rounded_vowel)

Comment: I would argue that this precision is going too far on here. It's a broad phonemic transcription, and not a fine-grained close phonetic one. I suspect that the actual pronunciations vary according to the speakers' native languages anyway.

Comment: OK, I have editted accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

You can find such tables (for **IPA**) on the Esperanto Wikipedia: [here](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononco_de_Esperanto#Literoj_kaj_fonemoj) and [here](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanta_alfabeto).

*Note*: **IFA** = Internacia fonetika alfabeto = **IPA** in English.

Answer (score 6):

Not to my knowledge for SAMPA. Tables of SAMPA transcriptions exist for several languages, and one for Esperanto should be easy to construct. An example for English is here: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/sampa/english.htm

The main page for SAMPA is at http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/sampa/index.html

An IPA table can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_Esperanto, but it has English equivalents.

Comment: This explains to an English speaker how to pronounce different SAMPA symbols, is there also a table converting Esperanto orthography into these symbols?

Comment: No, there isn't. You'd have to go via the IPA_for_Esperanto link to get the IPA, and then convert that into SAMPA from the main page listed. It should be trivial to do.

Comment: I agree, I will do one tonight.